# How can I use indexes with sort on a MongoDb $or query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've got a collection *mailCollection* with indexes on the .*sender* and .*recipient* values.  When I do an $or query and sort by .*timestamp* the entire collection is scanned.  How can I index this collection or rewrite the query to grab the documents where .*sender* or .*recipient* match a specific value, sorted and limited?

*mailCollection* indexes:

```
{recipient: 1}
{sender: 1}
```

Slow code:

```
email = <some email address I want to query>;
cursor = mailCollection.find({$or: [{sender: email}, {recipient: email}]});
cursor.sort({timestamp: 1}).limit(100).toArray(function(error, result) {
  //yikes, full collection scan
});
```

If it makes a difference, I'm using the MongoDb node.js driver.

Comment: Have you tried actually adding `timestamp` as an index? Have you tried adding `timestamp` as a secondary field in a compound index to either of the existing indexes? Perhaps read [Sort and Non-prefix Subset of an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index) add indexes and run with `explain()`. Use `hint()` if needed and then remove indexes that would not be picked up. No the driver does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dodgy. A 3-way index intersection does not work. So you need to intersect with a compound index. However, you need to make sure that you have a proper prefix in your compound index so that you have a proper use for it and make it efficient.

### The data

```
> db.indextest.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f401893e9fcadcbf2b1694"), "sender" : "me@example.com", "recipient" : "you@example.com", "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-28T04:03:21.468Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f405d93e9fcadcbf2b1695"), "sender" : "me@example.com", "recipient" : "somebody@example.com", "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-28T04:21:45.573Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f408413e9fcadcbf2b1699"), "sender" : "you@example.com", "recipient" : "somebody@example.com", "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-28T04:32:01.651Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f408563e9fcadcbf2b169a"), "sender" : "you@example.com", "recipient" : "me@example.com", "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-28T04:32:22.376Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f408763e9fcadcbf2b169b"), "sender" : "somebody@example.com", "recipient" : "you@example.com", "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-28T04:32:54.268Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f4087e3e9fcadcbf2b169c"), "sender" : "somebody@example.com", "recipient" : "me@example.com", "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-28T04:33:02.615Z") }
```

### The indices

I decided to create an index both on `sender` and `recipient` with an additional key on `timestamp`. This should give you efficient queries for the most common use cases:

- Which messages did a given user receive, sorted by date?
- Which messages did a given user send, sorted by date?
- And your query ;)

This gives you the most bang with the least overhead (one field in one index).

Given the indices

```
> db.indextest.getIndices()
[
  {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.indextest"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "recipient" : 1,
            "timestamp" : 1
        },
        "name" : "recipient_1_timestamp_1",
        "ns" : "test.indextest"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "sender" : 1,
            "timestamp" : 1
        },
        "name" : "sender_1_timestamp_1",
        "ns" : "test.indextest"
    }
]
```

### The result

Running your query:

```
> db.indextest.find({$or:[{sender:"you@example.com"},{recipient:"you@example.com"}]}).sort({timestamp:1}).explain()
```

gives the expected result (edited for brevity):

```
> db.indextest.find({$or:[{sender:"you@example.com"},{recipient:"you@example.com"}]}).sort({timestamp:1}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.indextest",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
...
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_MERGE",
                    "sortPattern" : {
                        "timestamp" : 1
                    },
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "recipient" : 1,
                                "timestamp" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "recipient_1_timestamp_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
...
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "recipient" : [
                                    "[\"you@example.com\", \"you@example.com\"]"
                                ],
                                "timestamp" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sender" : 1,
                                "timestamp" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sender_1_timestamp_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
...
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sender" : [
                                    "[\"you@example.com\", \"you@example.com\"]"
                                ],
                                "timestamp" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
...
    "ok" : 1
}
```

*EDIT*: Depending on your collection size, a sort merge might not be ideal.

Comment: Seems to have worked!  Thanks!  Just had to upgrade to the latest version of MongoDb to allow index intersection.